# Understanding how hash copy is behaving under the hood

Tags: ruby

I came out with an example of ruby hashes that I cannot quite understand what is happening under the hood:

```
root = {}
base = root
base[:a] = {}
base = base[:a]
p base
=> {}
p root
=> {:a=>{}}
```

When I assign `base = base[:a]` as I was expecting `base` becomes `{}`, but why `root` doesn't become `{}` too?

Comment: You didn't re-assign `root` so it still refers to the same object, i.e. the hash from line 1.

Comment: It's basically `root = 1`, `base = root`, `base = 2` – afterwards `base` refers to `2` and `root` (still) refers to `1`

Comment: `base = root` does not make these two identifiers be bound together for ever.  `root` is a pointer to some Hash object, which at that time happens to be empty. `base` is a pointer to the same underlying object, not a pointer to `root`. When you further down do a `base=`, you just assign a new pointer to `base`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just needed a little push to understand, and thanks to @Stefan I think I can answer my own question. Breaking it down we have:

```
root = {}
base = root
puts root.object_id
=> 47193371579760
puts base.object_id
=> 47193371579760
```

So both `root` and `base` became a reference for the same object.

```
base[:a] = {}
base[:a].object_id
=> 47193372751820
base = base[:a]
puts base.object_id
=> 47193372751820
puts root.object_id
=> 47193371579760
puts root
```

`base[:a]` is a new hash object, and `base` assigned to it becomes this object while `root` keeps the reference for the old object that was assigned `{:a=>{}}`. That's why `root` doesn't change at the end.

Comment: Yes; however while `base[:a]` is a new hash both `base` and `root[:a]` hold reference to it so `base[:b] = 12` will cause `root[:a][:b] == 12`, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Array, Symbol and Hash are some reference variables. Similar concept is present in all language. Taking example of javascript, we can relate same with concept of shallow copy & deep copy where hash is replaced by object.

Following is little explanation added for your query.

```
root = {}
# root = {}
base = root
# both base & root variables point to single location, principle of reference object
base[:a] = {}
# base aka root variable is holding value { a: {} }
base = base[:a]
# base variable is not pointing to root variable location, it is re-assigned with new value which is also hash (reference object)

p base
=> {}
p root
=> {:a=>{}}
base[:b] = 4
=> 4
p base
=> {:b=>4} 
p root
=> {:a=>{:b=>4}}
```

Using `object_id` function you can verify address. To make deep copy use `clone` function for hash.